# How to make bezier curve handles always visible

Tags: interface

How to make the bezier curve vertex handles always visible?

The points are only visible, when I select them, instead of always showing.

Where should I look for settings for this?

[image: vertex selected]

[image: vertex deselected]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While in *Edit Mode* in a curve, got the the 3D View header, under the overlays popover, towards the end under *Curve Edit Mode* change *Handles* to *All*.

[image]